# Redirect when not logged and parametr in link

Tags: redirect

how do I redirect to 'domain.com/sub' for unlogged users, when the url is without the "one_time_login" parameter?
This should not work when a user is trying to login via sub.domain.com/wp-admin.
Have no idea. I understand that htaccess cant make this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you're looking to achieve;

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page('one_time_login') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'domain.com/sub', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

This should be added to your theme (or child theme) functions.php file

Comment: really thanks for your help, finally its this code for me:

<code>  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in() && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "one_time_login_token") && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wp-admin") && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "new-login")) {
        wp_redirect( '/new-login', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
} </code>  ```